# Set the li active based on the url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Can someone help me to find what's the problem to my code? Im trying to set the `li` to active based on it's url. But the problem is nothing is set to active after loading. Give me ideas on how to do this or any alternative ways to do this?

**NOTE** the `$subj_descr` had a space ex. `COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 1`, `ENGLISH 2`

here's my php code where the `li` and `a` found.

```
<li data-popover="true" rel="popover" data-placement="right"><a href="#" data-target=".premium-menu" class="nav-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-book"></i> Lectures<i class="fa fa-collapse"></i></a></li>
    <li><ul id="wa" class="premium-menu nav nav-list collapse in">
    <?php
         $sql ="SELECT enroll_ref FROM std_enrolled WHERE stud_no = '$stud_no'";
           $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $enroll_ref = $row['enroll_ref'];
             }



              $sql3 ="SELECT DISTINCT subj_descr FROM subj_enrolled WHERE enroll_ref = '$enroll_ref'";
           $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
            $subj_descr = $row['subj_descr'];

    ?>

        <li id="<?php echo $subj_descr; ?>" ><a href="viewlecture.php?subjdescr=<?php echo $subj_descr;?>"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($subj_descr)); ?></a></li>
     <?php
      }  
     ?>
</ul></li>
```

here's my js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $(function(){
            var current = location.pathname;
            $('#wa li a').each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                // if the current path is like this link, make it active
                if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
                    $this.addClass('active');
                }
            })
        })
   });
```

Comment: why not just add that class active while printing inside the `while` block

Comment: If i add class active all of it will be active sir.

Comment: you only add the active class depending on whatever that condition you have, just use an `if` or just a simple ternary

Comment: I don't know how..

Comment: How your url looks like ?

Comment: viewlecture.php?subjdescr=COMPUTER%20PROGRAMMING%202 @Vignesh Chinnaiyan. it is `COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 2` it had a space.

Comment: Im in a localhost for now.

Comment: This is the complete url. localhost/studentportal/viewlecture.php?subjdescr=COMPUTER%20PROGRAMMING%202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function(){
        //location.search will give us query string i.e. part present after ? mark and ? itself which is nothing but ?subjdescr=COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 1 
        var current = decodeURIComponent(location.search); //decodeURIComponent to decode white space chars like %20 will get converted to white space 
        alert(current);
        $('#wa li a').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);

            alert(decodeURIComponent($this.attr('href')));

            // if the current path is like this link, make it active
            if(decodeURIComponent($this.attr('href')).indexOf(current) !== -1){

                $this.closest("li").addClass('active'); //setting the active class to parent li and not to a tag

            }
        })
    })
});
```

I guess you need to set `active` to `li` tag and not to `<a>` so just grab it via `$.closest()`

**Note:** added `decodeURIComponent()` to avoid encoded chars in string comparision

Comment: @wataru - can you try now. Better to `alert` strings before doing string comparison so that you will know what strings you are getting.

Comment: have you added the `alert(current);` and `alert(decodeURIComponent($this.attr('href')))`? what you get by this?

Comment: the result of the `alert(current);` is /studentportal/viewlecture.php

Comment: where should i put the? `          alert(decodeURIComponent($this.attr('href')));` ?

Comment: the result of `alert(decodeURIComponent($this.attr('href')));` is `viewlecture.php?subjdescr=COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 1` all of the subject in 2 loops.

Comment: please use `var current = decodeURIComponent(location.search);` instead of older one. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Can you explain sir? why it worked? i don't want to just copy that code.. i want to understand that.

Comment: added few comments in code. i hope it will help you to understand the logic.

Comment: Thankyou very much sir.

Comment: please don't call me sir because i am not...`;)`!

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

Replace `location.pathname` with `window.location.href`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function(){
    var current = window.location.href;
    $('#wa li').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      // if the current path is like this link, make it active
      if(current.indexOf($this.find('a').attr('href')) !== -1){
        $this.addClass('active');
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: @wataru I have updated the snippet. Initially the each loop was around a tag now it is on lis. Replace your code with mine.

Comment: Please use current.indexOf($this.find('a').attr('href')) instead of $this.find('a').attr('href').indexOf(current) in the if condition.

Comment: Yeah, But I have made change in the if condition of the snippet and updated just now. So check if it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this to find the text in the URL

```
 var my_url = "localhost/studentportal/viewlecture.php?subjdescr=COMPUTER%20PROGRAMMING%202";
        var found_my_url = my_url.search("viewlecture.php");
        var found_hashed = my_url.search("\\?");
        if(found_my_url!=-1 && found_hashed!=-1)
        {
    var url_split = my_url.split("?");
    var url_final = url_split[1].split("=");
    if(url_final[1]=="COMPUTER%20PROGRAMMING%202")
    {
    alert("Found in the URL");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("NOT FOUND in the URL");
    }
    }
```

Comment: My url is not static sir.

Comment: It's dynamic so it changes depends on the subject.

Comment: @wataru I have just give for demonstration, you can use `window.location.href` in the value of `my_url`.